# What is the ZF2 equivalent of the getPathInfo() method of ZF1?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

What is the ZF2 equivalent of the Request::getPathInfo() method from ZF1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$request = new \Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request();
var_dump($request->getUri());

object(Zend\Uri\Http)[5]
  protected 'validHostTypes' => int 19
  protected 'user' => null
  protected 'password' => null
  protected 'scheme' => string 'http' (length=4)
  protected 'userInfo' => null
  protected 'host' => string 'localhost' (length=9)
  protected 'port' => null
  protected 'path' => string '/iptcms/public_html/test.php' (length=28)
  protected 'query' => string '' (length=0)
  protected 'fragment' => null
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get path info from the **Uri** instance easily which accesible via **Request** instance.

In any controller action;

```
$path = $this->getRequest()->getUri()->getPath();
```

For more details, look over the [Zend\Uri](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Uri/Uri.php) and [Zend\Http\Request](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Http/Request.php) classes.

Comment: `getPath` in `Request` used as standalone module returns `null`. In ZF1 `getPathInfo` returned something like `/a/b/c`. Obviously I do something wrong here.

Comment: what do you mean by `standalone module`? try getting the 'Request' from service manager

Comment: @Exlord, I mean that I'm trying to use only `Request` class and its dependencies. Not the whole framework.